# How to get pass and fail test case count in UIAutomator

Tags: android-uiautomator

I am running multiple tests by using different classes.

ex: 
adb shell uiautomator runtest PrjoectXYZ.jar -c com.myapp.testautomation.NewUserRegistration

adb shell uiautomator runtest PrjoectXYZ.jar -c com.myapp.testautomation.Login

adb shell uiautomator runtest PrjoectXYZ.jar -c com.myapp.testautomation.Logout

And if i am redirecting the console output to a text file it is giving only the last ran result.

Can someone help me on getting the overall result with pass and fail counts ?

Comment: did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

In the Console output, you should find an "INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE:" for each test with a status of 0 or 1.
0 is Pass.
1 is fail.

So you want to build something custom? Maybe you can look at the source code for uiautomator2junit. thats what i use for reporting on Jenkins

https://github.com/dpreussler/automator-log-converter

Comment: Thank you for your response Tim, 
I just need to have a collective output of all the tests, like how many tests ran, how many tests pass and how many failed

Comment: @KrishnaMurthy Are you using Jenkins?

Comment: Yes Tim, I am using Jenkins and also there is a junit xml plug-in available in jenkins through that i am getting the over all report. But if i want the same way in host machine console ?